# What is the best way to load html as components?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a multiple pages website. I find it foolish to have to go into every html file to make simple changes to the header and footer. I am thinking about jquery load method but I hate using it. How should I go about doing this without without jquery.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_processor

Comment: so something like ejs?

Comment: I asked the exact same question many years ago. The thing you are looking for does not exist on browser side programming. You must be using some server sided languages like Java/PHP/Node.js to template your site (Mustache/Laravel Blade/pug) or with frameworks like Next.js/Nuxt. Or you can pre-compile your site using static site generators like Jekyll/Gatsby. Here I've given you some keywords. Do go look them up.

Comment: Create one `footer.html` one `header.html` and one `menu.html` and use PHP `include` for example (if you have PHP server) to include it in every page. then you are making changes in those files alone for all pages. https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_includes.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the other comments have said, there are multiple ways to do this.

As pointed out by User Daniel Chung, a good choice for this situation is using a website framework. I personally use Laravel Blade as it's a well-documented framework and is great for beginners. Laravel uses PHP and handles the backend. However, it includes Blade which uses html to do the frontend, this way you could use `@extends('template')` in your blade file, allowing you to pull in data from other blade(html) documents. [More info here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#extending-a-layout).

You could also use frontend frameworks like Vue.js or Next.js.

If you don't want to worry about frameworks, there are other ways to solve this problem. As user ikiK mentioned, using PHP includes allows you to perform just this. [This link](https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_includes.asp) from W3Schools is very useful and the first example they provide is basically exactly what you want.

I would recommend trying out some of the frameworks if you are building a complex website but if you need a simple fix, the PHP includes is the way to go.